# ios HTTP Post with string body

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, http-post, restkit

I am working on an ios application. I was provided a service that I can use to POST data to the server.
 They gave me a test link that I can use to see how the request is being sent. So I run fiddler and run the request and in the body they are sending the data in a weird format:

This is the request body:

```
formdata={"title" : "Test", "desc" : "Test desc"}&Token=g78ksyXQe1REuyFSkYbgWBqOqDzeseYJu
```

As you can see this is not a plain JSON body, so I dont know how I can send something similar from my app. 
I am using Restkit with AFNetworking to send other requests, but I can't just build the JSON from an object as it wont be that form.

So my question is how can I build this request body? and is there a way to build it as a string and just send it?

Thanks for any clarification

Comment: Sure, you can use RestKit or NSJSONSerialization to create the JSON part and then create the string using that if you want to

Answer (score -1):

1. Set Http Header

content-type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

1. Set Http Body

&title='Test'&desc='Test desc'&Token='g78ksyXQe1REuyFSkYbgWBqOqDzeseYJu'

Hope this will work for you.

BTW, if the Token is your access token, you might be able to set it in HTTP Header as well:

authorization : g78ksyXQe1REuyFSkYbgWBqOqDzeseYJu